# What is a single word that means false accusation?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've had an assignment that I would like to redo but use better/more intelligent words and phraseology and I'm stuck on this one.

Comment: Can you give an example sentence showing how the word might be used?

Comment: This post is closable based on SWR tag requirements, lack of research, lack of context, etc.

Comment: Do you mean specifically accusing someone of a crime they didn't do? I don't think there's a single word for that; it's usually called false accusation. Or more generally saying something bad and untrue?

Comment: Duplicate? https://english.stackexchange.com/q/26991/191178

Answer (score 1):

The word "*libel*" is one one the terms that can be used.

> ([OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/libel_1?q=libel))  the act of printing a statement about somebody that is not true and that gives people a bad opinion of them; the statement that is printed
> ♦ He sued the newspaper for libel.

More generally applicable is the word "*calumny*".

> ([OAld](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/calumny?q=calumny))  [countable] a false statement about a person that is made to damage their reputation
> ♦ He accused the press of publishing vicious calumnies.